# Getting GitHub's text styling

Tags: javascript, css, text

When you post an issue on GitHub, you can use different signs to make the issue itself look better and to display it in a different way.
For example, when using the (`) around a certain string, it will highlight it.

My question is, is it possible to somehow get that styling and use it in my own site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is called [Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown) markup language. On GitHub you can find many ready-made libraries like [marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked)